# Why does Facebook Open Graph metadata fail sometimes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have Open Graph meta tags in some of my web pages.  Sometimes when I Share the link to these pages in Facebook, the OG data is read and the page's proper description, image, etc. are displayed in FB.  Other times, it doesn't -- it just shows the URL of the page (and yes, it does link to the page properly.)

Anyone ever have this experience?  Think this is a FB bug or might I be doing something wrong?

For the record, I did run it through the FB OG debugger and got no errors.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts/ideas!

Comment: At the *severe* risk of making it look like I'm promoting our site, which I am not, here is an example of one of the pages where we use OG metadata:  http://www.petchance.org/chances/11

Answer (score 0):

I've tried few times, I think you need just wait until publication popup loaded completly. If I paste a link immediately after opening the popup, OG don't work.

#### UPDATE:

OG start to work after sending this request
www.facebook.com/react_composer/feedx_sprouts/bootload/?composer_id=rc.u_0_z&target_id=000000000000000&composer_type=feedx_sprouts&friend_list_id=